# Как вывести элемент из листа на экран?

Tags: java

Пытаюсь создать простой калькулятор, стараясь при этом не усложнять код создавая слушателя для каждой кнопки, а вместо этого создал

```
ArrayList<JButton> number = new ArrayList<JButton>();
```

и девять кнопок через цикл

```
 for(int i=0;i<9;i++) {
        String num = ""+i;
        JButton btn = new JButton(num);
        btn.addActionListener(new allButtons());
        number.add(btn);
        pn.add(btn);
    }
```

Проблема в том, что не могу при нажатии на кнопку отобразить именно ее индекс, т.е. значение. Пробовал через такой код, но что-то ему не хватает:

```
public void howDoBut() {
    for(int i=0; i<9;i++) {
        JButton jcheck = (JButton)number.get(i);
        if(jcheck.isEnabled()) {
            txt.setText(""+i);
        }
    }
public class allButtons implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        howDoBut();

    }

}
```

Comment: Что такое txt? А так, полагаю проблема в том, что Вы изменяете кнопку jcheck, которой нет на экране

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант 1.**

Поскольку у вас каждой кнопке передается новый экземпляр `allButtons`, самый простой вариант решения проблемы - сделать у `allButtons` приватное поле, которое инициализировать конструктором. То есть

```
public class AllButtons implements ActionListener {
private int digit;

public AllButtons(int digit) {
this.digit = digit;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    txt.setText("" + digit);
}
```

Ну а в цикле будет

```
for(int i=0;i<9;i++) {
    String num = ""+i;
    JButton btn = new JButton(num);
    btn.addActionListener(new AllButtons(i));
    number.add(btn);
    pn.add(btn);
}
```

**Вариант 2.**

Сделать **один** слушатель для всех кнопок, объявить его в виде приватного поля в классе, где создаются кнопки. Тогда в цикле не надо создавать новый экземпляр, а использовать значение из приватного поля. Далее, в обработчике события получить источник сообщения (как писали выше)

```
JButton clicked = (JButton)e.getSource();
```

Далее, у вас есть объект. Этот объект передаем как параметр в метод `howDoBut()`

```
public void howDoBut(JButton source) {
    txt.setText("" + number.indexOf(source))
}
```

P.S. Добавить проверки по вкусу.